# Why do Wolverine's claws have blades?

Tags: marvel, x-men, wolverine

*Disclaimer:* My knowledge of the x-men franchise comes from the films, not comics or cartoons. Sorry if the answer is obvious in a different medium.

Okay, so Wolverine, of the X-men, has claws. They are shape in a knife-like way, with a sharp blade on one side, but I'm nor sure they should. Here's some known facts.

- His mutation provides two powers, an ability to heal almost any wound at high speed (which also allows him to never visibly age), and retractable bone claws.
- The claws are comprised of multiple bones, resembling the bone structure of hands and feet.
- His bones were infused with an alien metal, Adamantium, at a later date by William Stryker.
- The rest of his bones are the same shape (we see x-rays, they're normal).
- We see him escape immediately after the metal is implanted, there's no time for someone to add more metal or sharpen the blades.

So why would they be bladed, and not the same shape as they used to be?

Comment: Maybe Stryker had the original bone claws carved into blade-like shapes before encasing them in adamantium?  Specifically so that they could be used as blades instead of stilettos afterwards.  Logan's regeneration doesn't expulse the adamantium from his body, so once encased in the metal, his bone claws would be unable to regenerate into their natural shape.

Comment: in the x-rays you see several bones are more angular than they should be  (the brow ridge for instance) so maybe the process makes the bones more angular. the bone claws are quite flattened, like lumpy blades.  make a flattened shape more angular and you get a blade.